# Safetransfer Vs transfer

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Does anyone know the difference between safeTransfer and transfer in ERC20?

People said that safeTransfer returns boolean, which is much safer than "transfer"?

I do not understand it well,
When you use either the safeTransfer or transfer function to send tokens more than the tokens you have, the both function returns an error.

I feel like they seem same,

Would you please help me?

if possible, please give me a example code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From OpenZepplain's forum.

> SafeERC20 is not an ERC20 extension that you use to make your token safe (OpenZeppelin’s ERC20 is already safe). **It’s a helper to make safe the interaction with someone else’s ERC20 token, in your contracts**.

You can read the full post [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/safeerc20-tokentimelock-wrappers/396).

Answer (score 3):

There is no `safeTransfer` in ERC20. If you're talking about ERC721 then `safeTransfer` calls a function on the receiver that makes sure they're aware of the ERC721 standard and will know what to do with the token while `transfer` doesnt.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain it well, I meant the function safeTransfer in the SafeERC20 Library